# Yii 1.1: Fetching HAS_MANY between two models

Tags: php, yii, has-many

Our platform is build using Yii 1.1. We have users with `staff` role, and they have permissions granted to them.

**`client_staff`**

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code         | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| clientId     | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| emailAddress | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| firstName    | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName     | varchar(45)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| archivedAt   | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**`staff_permissions`**

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code         | varchar(20)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| staffId      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| permissionId | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| createdAt    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt    | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**`permissions`**

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code        | varchar(20)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt   | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt   | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A `client_staff` has many `staff_permissions`, which belongs to `permission`.

Using the framework, I wanna to fetch the `staff_permissions` along with the `client_staff`, so this is how I tried configured the `relations` in `ClientStaff`:

```
return [
  'client' => [self::BELONGS_TO, User::class, 'clientId'],
  'staffPermission' => [self::HAS_MANY, StaffPermission::class, 'id'],
]
```

in `StaffPermission`:

```
return [
  'staff' => [self::BELONGS_TO, ClientStaff::class, 'staffId'],
  'permissions' => [self::HAS_MANY, Permission::class, 'permissionId'],
]
```

and in `Permission`:

```
return [
  'staffPermissions' => [self::BELONGS_TO, StaffPermission::class, 'id'],
]
```

We have a `toAPICopy` method to bring the data to the client in JSON, and in this method, for classes `BELONGS_TO`, we make use of each classes' `toAPICopy` within the returned array. Below's the case of `ClientStaff`

```
public function toAPICopy()
{
  return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'client' => $this->client->toAPICopy(),
    ...,
    'staffPermission' => $this->staffPermission->toAPICopy()
  ];
}
```

But nothing happens and the application hangs. No data is fetched and no error is shown, not a single thing in `api.log` file to help me. I do not know what I could've done wrong.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong with your relationships. eg.
`return [
  'client' => [self::BELONGS_TO, User::class, 'clientId'],
  'staffPermission' => [self::HAS_MANY, StaffPermission::class, 'staffId'],
]`
let me explain in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `HAS_MANY` will return an array of objects, therefore, you cannot call a method directly on it. The solution that worked for me is:

```
public function toAPICopy() {
  foreach ($this->staffPermissions as $p) {
   array_push($permissions, $p->toAPICopy();
  }

  return [ ... 'staffPermissions' => $permissions, ... ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having some issue in making relations.

these are the relations as per your table structure.

ClientStaff should be:

```
return [
  'client' => [self::BELONGS_TO, User::class, 'clientId'],
  'staffPermission' => [self::HAS_MANY, StaffPermission::class, 'staffId'],
]
```

in StaffPermission should be:

```
return [
  'staff' => [self::BELONGS_TO, ClientStaff::class, 'staffId'],
  'permissions' => [self::BELONGS_TO, Permission::class, 'permissionId'],
]
```

and in Permission should be:

```
return [
  'staffPermissions' => [self::BELONGS_TO, StaffPermission::class, 'permissionId'],
]
```

Comment: I get the error "nonce already used" when I attempt to bring the `StaffPermissions`.

Comment: in clientstaff relation?

Comment: are you using any GoogleAppsAuthentification @mfgabriel92

Comment: Nothing. Now I managed to make it partially work. I changed the `HAS_MANY` to `BELONGS_TO` and only one data is being fetched, even though it has more. That is the only way I managed to make it work. Before, the error that Insomnia (REST API) showed me was that `toAPICopy()` was being executed from an array.

Comment: Have you found anything new in this issue? or its already resolved

Comment: I'm still stuck. By using `HAS_MANY`, an array is returned, hence the error. But `toAPICopy()` is necessary or else no data is returned. The whole application has DB models with this same method, but I guess this is the only occasion it uses `HAS_MANY`. If I do not call it, only an array with empty objects is returned.

Comment: I just had a click on my mind, and I found the solution. I looped over the `HAS_MANY` variable I created and assigned it to a new array. It worked.

Comment: Can you show me what you have code in `toAPICopy()` function?

Comment: I am thinking that why you just don't add code there in the `toAPICopy()` function to check whether it is an array or object?